# JMeter ConcurrencyThreadGroup object creation throws java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError error

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to upgrade my JMeter DSL implementation to the latest JMeter version(5.4.3). But I got an issue with ConcurrencyThreadGroup object creation, it throws an exception. See the below exception

Using following versions

JMeter 5.4.3

jmeter-plugins-standard 1.4.0

Method implementation

```
public ConcurrencyThreadGroup getConcurrencyThreadGroup(String name, String targetConcurrency,
                                                            String rampUpTime, String rampUpStepCount, String timeUnit, String holdTargetTime,
                                                            boolean setEnabled
    ) {
        
        ConcurrencyThreadGroup concurrencyThreadGroup = new ConcurrencyThreadGroup();
        concurrencyThreadGroup.setName(name);
        concurrencyThreadGroup.setTargetLevel(targetConcurrency);
        concurrencyThreadGroup.setRampUp(rampUpTime);
        concurrencyThreadGroup.setSteps(rampUpStepCount);
        concurrencyThreadGroup.setUnit(timeUnit);
        concurrencyThreadGroup.setHold(holdTargetTime);
        concurrencyThreadGroup.setEnabled(setEnabled);
        concurrencyThreadGroup.setProperty("TestElement.test_class", ConcurrencyThreadGroup.class.getName());
        concurrencyThreadGroup.setProperty("TestElement.gui_class", ConcurrencyThreadGroupGui.class.getName());
      
        return concurrencyThreadGroup;
    }
```

Observing below exception when try to execute

```
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.<init>(ResultCollector.java:167)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.<init>(ResultCollector.java:157)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.reporters.FlushingResultCollector.<init>(FlushingResultCollector.java:7)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.AbstractDynamicThreadGroupModel.<init>(AbstractDynamicThreadGroupModel.java:28)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.AbstractDynamicThreadGroup.<init>(AbstractDynamicThreadGroup.java:23)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup.<init>(ConcurrencyThreadGroup.java:11)
    at org.qa.perf.jmeter.api.threadgroups.QADSLThreadGroup.getConcurrencyThreadGroup(QADSLThreadGroup.java:136)
    at org.qa.perf.jmeter.dsl.QADSLJMeterDSL.concurrencyThreadGroup(QADSLJMeterDSL.java:93)
    at org.qa.perf.dsl.sample.threadgroup.ConcurrencyThreadGroupSampleTest$1.prepareJMeterTestPlan(ConcurrencyThreadGroupSampleTest.java:20)
    at org.qa.perf.jmeter.engine.QADSLPerfTestClient.executeTest(QADSLPerfTestClient.java:29)
    at org.qa.perf.dsl.sample.threadgroup.ConcurrencyThreadGroupSampleTest.testConcurrencyThreadGroupSampleTest(ConcurrencyThreadGroupSampleTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration.<clinit>(SampleSaveConfiguration.java:287)
    ... 38 more
```

Appreciate any clue or solution to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to show your full code and full stacktrace as the partials unfortunately don't tell the full story.

Most probably you didn't load [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) which are responsible for the [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) so my expectation is that you need to call the following function somewhere in the beginning of your code:

```
org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter.properties")
```

More information:

- [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/) example project